# Authentication issue in VSCode Rest Client

Tags: rest, asp.net-core

I have an api in a asp.net core web app.  it works fine when I run the app and access the get endpoint in the browser.  but when I try to test it in vscode using the rest client extension I get this response,

```
GET https://localhost:7264/test


HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Date: Thu, 27 Apr 2023 16:07:44 GMT
Server: Kestrel
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
```

the asp.net core app is using windows authentication.  so I do not understand why its not working since I am logged into windows and it works when I run from the browser.

is there some option that I need to add.  What's strange is a this was working before no problems

I tried looking through the README.md on github for the client but did not see anything on windows authentication.

Edits

---

#### test.rest

```
GET https://localhost:7077/MapGetTest HTTP/1.1
```

#### program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
   .AddNegotiate();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // By default, all incoming requests will be authorized according to the default policy.
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.MapGet("/MapGetTest",() => { return "Hello World"; });

app.Run();
```

Comment: Hows your Test details and program.cs file ? Could you include that within the question? so that it can be reproduced exactly.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron i edited the post to include the program.cs and the test.rest file.  this is a new asp.net core web app template with windows selected as the auth.  the only change i made to that default template was teh app.mapget method.  which works in the browser  but not the test.rest